# XSD problem: The value of attribute on element is not valid with respect to its type

Tags: xml, schema, xsd

(First of all, I'm trying to learn how to handle xsd files, I know very little)

I got [this](http://www.daisy.org/DRM/KeyExchange-2005-1.xsd) xsd, and just copy to Eclipse IDE, and it says there an error on line 26:

```
<xs:element name="Issuer" type="dkx:IssuerType" />
```

saying:

> cvc-attribute.3: The value
>   'dkx:IssuerType' of attribute 'type'
>   on element 'xs:element' is not valid
>   with respect to its type, 'QName'.

Everything in this error message is in the specified line, except the "QName" (what is it?).

Any idea how to solve this? (as this is an example file, I'm assuming it is an independent file, hope it is)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found: I was using wrong file extension, ".xml", while the correct is ".xsd".

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the type `dkx:IssuerType` has not been defined, according to Eclipse.

Maybe you should start with a more basic overview and work your way through. 
Try this: http://www.w3schools.com/Schema/default.asp

Comment: Thanks, I'm reading some tutorials, but I'm really looking for this issue answer now.

Comment: maybe the dkx is defined in one of the imports, but why would Eclipse raise an error if so? I mean, when we import something, it is like it was there in the same file, so that should not give an error..

Comment: Right.  But maybe it is NOT defined in any of the imports.