# Ionic-Project + Eclipse Neon: Errors in config.xml

Tags: xml, ionic-framework, xml-validation, eclipse-neon, jboss-developer-studio

I'd like to use Eclipse Neon + JBoss Developer Studio with Ionic (on Windows 10). After setting up the 'getting started' project of Ionic and importing it to Eclipse, there are a lot of validation errors in the config.xml. I haven't edited a single file. I can simulate the project with *Cordova/Sim*, but somehow a lot of red flags in the Eclipse project don't look very nice.

The following types of errors are an extract of those shown in the Eclipse Problem-View:

- cvc-attribute.3: The value 'android-minSdkVersion' of attribute 'name' on element 'preference' is not valid with respect to its type
- cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'onload' is not allowed to appear in element 'param'.
- cvc-enumeration-valid: Value 'android-minSdkVersion' is not facet-valid with respect to enumeration '[AllowInlineMediaPlayback, AndroidLaunchMode, android-maxSdkVersion, android-targetSdkVersion, AppendUserAgent, BackgroundColor, BackupWebStorage, ChildBrowser, CordovaWebViewEngine, DefaultVolumeStream, DisallowOverscroll, EnableViewportScale, EnableWebGL, ErrorUrl, FullScreen, GapBetweenPages, HideKeyboardFormAccessoryBar, HideMousePointer, InAppBrowserStorageEnabled, KeepRunning, KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction, LoadUrlTimeoutValue, LoadingDialog, LogLevel, MediaPlaybackAllowsAirPlay, MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction, Min/Max Version, Orientation, OSXLocalStoragePath, OverrideUserAgent, PageLength, PaginationBreakingMode, PaginationMode, PopupBlocker, SetFullscreen, ShowTitle, Suppresses3DTouchGesture, SuppressesIncrementalRendering, SuppressesLongPressGesture, TopActivityIndicator, UIWebViewDecelerationSpeed, WebSecurity, WindowSize, WindowsDefaultUriPrefix, WindowsStoreDisplayName, WindowsStoreIdentityName, WindowsStorePublisherName, WindowsToastCapable, deployment-target, target-device, windows-phone-target-version, windows-target-version]'. It must be a value from the enumeration.

Here are some Screenshots, that might be of interest:

[Screenshot from Eclipse Problem-View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPeGl.png)

[Screenshot of Eclipse Workspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANM70.png) (with some added files, but the errors stay the same)

Since I don't have enough reputation, I can't add more links in my post, but I try to provide more info, when needed.

Comment: Have you tried to google it before asking?
The first in the google for your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813257/xsd-problem-the-value-of-attribute-on-element-is-not-valid-with-respect-to-its

Comment: Yeah, I googled and also stumbled on your link. I don't want to define an xsd-file (and name it xml). I'm talking about an untouched tutorial file, that throws a lot of errors, but it's entries are correct (at least due to https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/ )

Answer (score 0):

Those errors shown on config.xml screenshot reported because xml is not valid. Schema used in validation comes from Eclipse Thyme and actual file can be seen [here](https://github.com/eclipse/thym/blob/master/plugins/org.eclipse.thym.core/res/w3c-xsd/packaging-configuration.xsd).

You can ether totally disable xml validation or exclude config.xml from validation in project's preferences.